# Uploading to Shiny and assigning it to environment for further use

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny dashboard where the user can upload data sets, naming them, and then selecting one data set from a dropdown menu.

I dont fully understand how a user can upload a data, save it and further access it. I tried using `assign()`, but the dataset does not show up under `ls()`. My try:

```
library(data.table)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinydashboard)


if (interactive()) {

  ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                  accept = c(
                    "text/csv",
                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                    ".csv")
        ),

        actionButton('show_ls', 'show_ls'),

                         # Name data

        textInput('name_data', 'Store data as' , value = ''),

                         # Action button to upload

        actionButton('upload_data', 'Upload and save data')



        ),

      mainPanel(
        tableOutput('ls')
        #  textOutput('ls'))
      )
    )
  )



  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # This part uploads one row from the file, so the user can selects columns and choose name of the file

    data <- reactive({
      file1 <- input$file1

      if(is.null(file1)){return()}

      data_input <- fread(file=file1$datapath, sep=",")

      updateTextInput(
        session,
        'name_data',
        value = file1$name
      )

      return(data_input)


    })



    #### ASSIGNING THE DATA

    assign_data <- eventReactive(input$upload_data, {

      assign(input$name_data, data(), envir = .GlobalEnv)

    })

    assign_the_data <- reactive(assign_data())


    output$contents <- renderTable({

      if(is.null(data())) return(NULL)

      data()

    })

    outputOptions(output, 'contents', suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

    show_ls <- eventReactive(input$show_ls, {data.frame(a = ls(.GlobalEnv))})

    output$ls <- renderTable({

      show_ls()

    })





  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `assign()` can be difficult because the search path through the namespace can be difficult to predict. A better solution would be to store the datasets in a reactive values list and access them from there. You can dynamically render the dataset picker UI based on the names of the datasets stored in the reactive values list.

```r
if (interactive()) {
  ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(
        "file1",
        "Choose CSV File",
        accept = c(
          "text/csv",
          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
          ".csv"
        )
      ),

      # Name data

      textInput('name_data', 'Store data as' , value = ''),

      # Action button to upload

      actionButton('upload_data', 'Upload and save data')

    ),

    mainPanel(uiOutput("dataset_picker"),
              tableOutput('selected_table')
              #  textOutput('ls')))
    ))



    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      # This part uploads one row from the file, so the user can selects columns and choose name of the file
      dfs <- reactiveValues()

      observeEvent(input$upload_data, {
        req(input$file1, input$name_data)
        dfs[[input$name_data]] <- read.csv(input$file1$datapath[1])
        print(names(dfs))
      })

      output$dataset_picker <- renderUI({
        req(length(dfs) > 0)
        pickerInput(
          "dataset_picker",
          label = "Choose dataset",
          choices = names(reactiveValuesToList(dfs)),
          selected = NULL
        )
      })


      output$selected_table <- renderTable({
        req(input$dataset_picker)
        dfs[[input$dataset_picker]]

      })


    }

    shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```